# Получить класс Message зная его message_id и chat_id

Tags: python, aiogram

Хотелось бы создать волшебную функцию `get_message(chat_id, message_id)`. Как это сделать?

Comment: И что вы хотите потом делать? Какие цели у этой задачи?

Comment: Например я хочу получить это сообщение и ответить на него, но в другом чате

Comment: Нельзя ответить на сообщение в боте, находясь в другом чате

Comment: Я раньше делал так, сначала брал сообщение, копировал его в другой чат и отвечал на него, но минус в том, что будет появляться сообщение